# Compile VB.net with Alea GPU programming

Tags: vb.net, gpu

I'm new to GPU programming and I'm using Alea with VB.Net 2013

I tried to write a simple for loop but I'm having some compilation errors on the For loop. I tried several syntax but non of them is working.

```
    Imports Alea
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks
    Imports Alea.Gpu

    Public Class MyClass
        Private Sub TestingGPU(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

            Dim Length As Integer = 1000
            Dim MyGPU As Gpu = Gpu.Default

            Dim Arg1 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray()
            Dim Arg2 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray()
            Dim Result = New Integer(Length - 1) {}

            Dim opFactory As Func(Of Integer(), Action(Of Integer)) = Function(res) Function(i)
                                                                                        res(i) = Arg1(i) + Arg2(i)
                                                                                    End Function

            Gpu.Default.for(0, Result.Length, opFactory(Result))   'Compilation Error : For is not a member of Alea.GPU
            Gpu.Default.[for](0, Result.Length, opFactory(Result)) 'Compilation Error : For is not a member of Alea.GPU
            MyGPU.for(0, Result.Length, opFactory(Result))         'Compilation Error : For is not a member of Alea.GPU
            MyGPU.[for](0, Result.Length, opFactory(Result))       'Compilation Error : For is not a member of Alea.GPU
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Does anyone know the reason of the error please ?

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: And the reason is ... that is not how you write a `for` loop?

Comment: What are you trying to get from the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import namespace **Imports Alea.Parallel**. And then, all the errors are gone :d. Hope to help and Happy new year, my friend :))

Comment: Works like charm ! Thank you and happy new year :) !

Comment: @ThomasCarlton: Well played, my friend :))